# DLIB OpenCv integration (toMat()) throwing compiler error

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

what I'm trying to do is using DLIBs `toMat()` function to convert an DLIB face detection to an OpenCV `Mat` for postprosessing.

So far DLIB works fine. E.g. using the [`face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp`](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) thats included in the examples as well. (Meaning I can pass in an image and get the landmarking output)

Even adding of the required include `#include <dlib/opencv.h>` works without issues.

But as soon as I add the line `toMat(img);` (Not even jet assigning it to an OpenCv `Mat`) I revice the following compiler error:

> Cannot open include file : 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' : No such file or directory

thrown by `C:\dlib-19.4\dlib-19.4\dlib\opencv\cv_image.h`

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

PS: After I added `#include <dlib/opencv.h>` intelisense starts suggesting me `toMat(img);` so the files should be present (at least for the declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this entry was missing in the `Properties > Linker > Input`

> C:\OpenCv\build\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world320.lib

or (more dynamical):

> $(OPENCV_DIR)\lib\opencv_world320.lib

**BUT** it's not working if I add this to an `"Additional" Property Sheet`. It need to be added to the `Project Properties` itself (don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler cannot find the `opencv2/core` directory for including `core.hpp`.
Did you add the
`C:\dlib-19.4\dlib-19.4\dlib` to your compiler's include directories?

Comment: Yes nearly. I added `C:\dlib-19.4\dlib-19.4\dlib\..`(it was already in the example). If I add `C:\dlib-19.4\dlib-19.4\dlib` I get the error "C1189 #error:  "Don't put the dlib folder in your include path""